# How do I disable auto-away for online presence?

Tags: 11.04, empathy, skype, instant-messaging

I am using Natty with with classic GNOME desktop.

I use Empathy and sometimes Skype.

Both these get the online state from the system itself somehow.

If I don't touch my keyboard for a few minutes - even when watching a YouTube clip or something - the inactivity triggers an auto-away state on my messaging apps.

It's synchronized so I imagine its coming coordinated from the system, and not the two apps making the same decision individually.

How can I disable this?  I want manual control - I'm only `away` when I set it to away in a messaging app.

Answer (score 5):

Install `dconf-tools` and open `dconf-editor`.

Go to `org.gnome.Empathy` and change `autoaway` like you want.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

#### Empathy

Empathy has a default auto-away configured. If you want to change it, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `dconf-editor`. On the left hand side you'll a tree view. Click on apps -> empathy. Now you see some settings on the right. The first line is the auto-away setting. If you uncheck it, Empathy will not automatically set you away.

#### Skype

At SuperUser.com is a nice answer regarding to Skype: [Does my Skype status ever change to 'Away' automatically?](https://superuser.com/a/202558)

Answer (score 1):

Years later, and a similar problem. I use Skype with Lubuntu and the "show me as away after 0 seconds setting" has no effect.

Changing this line in the Skype config.xml so that the value is 0 instead of 1800 worked for me.

```
<IdleTimeForNA>1800</IdleTimeForNA>
```